# How many Speed boost mods can be applied to an Aegis's Astral Skin?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

The aegis Astral skin has the Speed option twice as free as bonus mods, however the *Speed* option state:

> **Speed**
>
> The aegis’s base land speed is increased by 5 feet. This customization can be selected up to five times. Its effects stack

Now does this mean the option can be taken a total of five times flat and stack or that it can add a maximum of 5 times, in addition, the 2 Speed mods that the Aegis' Astral Skin already come with?

So, Astral Skin max speed with CP:

- Speed x5 = +25 feet to base speed, or
- Speed x7 = +35 feet to base speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can take it three more times.

The ability states that you gain two levels (+10 ft) for free, but doesn't mention increasing that limit of 5 levels (+25 ft). Which means that you simply don't have to buy those mods with your pool points, you gained them for free.

This is explained under [Customizing your Astral Suit](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/aegis/astral-suits#TOC-Customizations):

> Each astral suit provides certain **free customizations**; these are provided on top of whatever customizations the aegis pays for with customization points, and are not subject to the usual level prerequisites or increased costs. If the aegis changes the type of his astral suit and the free customizations would take the suit over the maximum limit (such as switching from an Astral Armor with 3 Nimble customizations to Astral Skin, which grants an additional Nimble customization), **the excess customizations go inert until the astral suit is changed to make the selections valid** (by reconfiguring the customization points via 8 hours of concentration or Reconfigure ability or switching the astral suit type).